# Should I create my controllers the way I want the URL to look?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a few questions about links in Zend. First, I want my links to look nice, so should I name my controllers the way I want my links to look? or is there a way to manipulate URLs? Also, what is the proper way to link to a controller in view? The obvious way is to just use `domain.com/controller/action`, but I get the feeling this isn't the best way especially if I could manipulate URL names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Routers http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Answer (score 0):

## Zend_Controller_Router

You can use the router.

It's normal to call your Controllers and Actions something that might be similar to your Routes, but when you use a Route, you can change anything you need.

There are lots of different routes available, so you can "match" lots of different URLs.

Here are the standard ones:

[Zend_Controller_Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

- Zend_Controller_Router_Route
- Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static
- Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex
- Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname

You can also use any of the above routes, and chain them together using:

- Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain

## The Basic Operation

You would create your routes, (generally in your Bootstrap), and have lots of them. These then "match" against the Request object in order to route the request to the correct Controller and Action.

The default route is like `/:module/:controller/:action`

But if you want you can create anything.

This is a sample from the Docs, and will match a URL like `/author/Doug`, which will then Route the request to the Default module, the `profile` Controller, and the `userinfo` Action.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'author/:username',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action'     => 'userinfo'
    )
);

$router->addRoute('user', $route);
```